# How can i write $\sqrt[4]{y}$ in sagemath

Tags: sagemath

Well i know i that can write the square root as sqrt(y) but i want to be able to write $\sqrt[4]{y}$ and can't find any information anywhere about how it's done. Hope somebody knows if it's possible and in that case help me out here.

Comment: Maybe this works: real_nth_root(x, n). You could also use (y)^(0.25) - See: https://www.integral-domain.org/lwilliams/math150/sage/basic.php